# Keyboard shortcut to stop application in QtCreator

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

When I want to run my app in QtCreator I use combination of `Ctrl + r`, but I can't seem to find similar shortcut for stopping the app once it started (i.e. keyboard shortcut for `Stop` button on `Application Output` pane. It annoys me that I have to use mouse for stopping it.

I run this app on remote device, but I don't think it is important in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options`, select `Environment` and `Keyboard` tab.

Search for: *stop* and set a Shortcut for **ProjectExplorer**->Stop.

[image]